# Passing associative array through AJAX to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass this to a PHP script through AJAX:

```
  var answers={};
  for (x=0; x< allAnswers.length; x++)
   {
       answers.x=new Array();
       answers.x['id']==allAnswers[x]['id'];
       answers.x['val']=$("#field_" + x).val();
   }

   var data={};
   data.id=questions[qId]['id'];
   data['answers']=answers;

   $.post('index.php',data);
```

The PHP is set to `print_r($_POST)`, and this is the output:

```
answers [object Object]

id       3
```

What am I done wrong?

Edit: Changing the code to use arrays, i.e:

```
  var answers=new Array();
   for (x=0; x< allAnswers.length; x++)
   {
       answers[x]=new Array();
       answers[x]['id']=allAnswers[x]['id'];
       answers[x]['val']=$("#field_" + x).val();
   }
   var data={};
   data.id=questions[qId]['id'];
   data['answers[]']=answers;

   $.post('index.php',data);
```

Gives this print_r:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [answers] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

)
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're redeclaring answers.x over and over so you're only going to get the last one.  x is the actual variable name and not the value you're thinking. Also you have a double equal on the "allAnswers" line. try:

```
var answers = new Array();
for (x=0; x< allAnswers.length; x++)
   {
       answers[ x ]=new Array();
       answers[ x ]['id'] = allAnswers[x]['id'];
       answers[ x ]['val'] = $("#field_" + x).val();
   }
```

Comment: The 2nd assignment also has a double equal, so it's never assigning the answer id.

Comment: See my edit for the output i get from changing ansers to an array

Answer (score 6):

Replace this:

```
var answers=new Array();
for (x=0; x< allAnswers.length; x++) {
    answers[x]=new Array();
    answers[x]['id']=allAnswers[x]['id'];
    answers[x]['val']=$("#field_" + x).val();
}
```

With this:

```
var answers = new Array();
for (x=0; x< allAnswers.length; x++) {
    answers[x] = {};
    answers[x]['id']=allAnswers[x]['id'];
    answers[x]['val']=$("#field_" + x).val();
}
```

You want an array of objects, not an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Ah that makes more sense; the way you had it formatted previously didn't match the input.

Anyhoo, the answers object is a JavaScript object; PHP doesn't know how to handle it. I suggest you parse out the individual items prior to passing to PHP, or use json_decode() on the PHP side.